# Can't maximize browser window by using selenium webDriver on local MAC machine

Tags: selenium, web, automation, webdriver

I"m trying to maximize browser window by using this Java code:

```
webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Is there any other option for this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Toolkit utility.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class MaximizeBrowser {

    @Test
    public void test()
    {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        int Width = (int) toolkit.getScreenSize().getWidth();
        int Height = (int)toolkit.getScreenSize().getHeight();
        //For Dimension class, Import following library "org.openqa.selenium.Dimension"  
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(Width,Height));
        // Your code here
        driver.quit();
        }


}
```

Comment: Great solution. I added also webDriver.manage().window().maximize(); in the end, cause the browser window was a little far from the top right edge.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your trying to call a `native` driver method on Firefox when you need to use Firefox 31.6.0 ESR , because later versions of Firefox don't support native.  To work around this, use Chrome instead.